# Other objects getting effected by the movement of one object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So i am currently starting to really get into game design and have a question: I currently have a spinning platform, but if i put an object or my player on it they dont get moved by the rotation! is there any simple way to make the other objects get turned too?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building a rotating platform in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891966/building-a-rotating-platform-in-unity)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to react when an object hits your rotating platform and set it as a child of this.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
{
    col.transform.parent = transform;
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
{
    col.transform.parent = null;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45891966/building-a-rotating-platform-in-unity)